# tomahawk selectBooleanCheckbox and java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, checkbox

Need some assistance  with an issuing I am having with a t:selectBooleanCheck and a javascript.  I have several checkboxes which become visible on certain conditions which all call a javascript method to disable and enable buttons on the page.

I have move one of the checkboxes to its own column to make a better display. Since I move the checkbox, the javascript method doesn't recognize it as part of the set checkboxes. I believe this to be the functionality that goes with JSF.

**myPage.jspx**

```
function checkBoxSelectedCountIgnoreId(collection, ignoreId) {
count = 0;
for (i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
    elem = collection[i];
    if (elem == null) {
        break;
    }else if (elem.checked && elem.id == ignoreId) {
        //dont count ignoreId in checkbox checked count
    }else if (elem.checked) {
        count++;
    }
}
return count;
}

function manageCommandButtons(checkbox) {
        parentTD = checkbox.parentNode;
        parentTR = parentTD.parentNode;
        parentTBODY = parentTR.parentNode;
        checkBoxCollection = parentTBODY.getElementsByTagName("input");


        var printBtn = "printBtn";
        var printIpadBtn = "printIpadBtn";
        var emailBtn = "emailBtn";
        var formId = checkbox.form.name;

        var checkBoxCount = checkBoxSelectedCountIgnoreId(checkBoxCollection,"summaryFrm:shuttleIncluded");
        /*
         * disabling email button for now, always.
         */
        if (checkBoxCount == 1) {
            disableObject(formId, printBtn, false);
            disableObject(formId, printIpadBtn, false);
            disableObject(formId, emailBtn, false);
        } else {
            if (checkBoxCount > 1) {
                disableObject(formId, printBtn, true);
                disableObject(formId, printIpadBtn, true);
                disableObject(formId, emailBtn, false);
            } else {
                disableObject(formId, printBtn, true);
                disableObject(formId, printIpadBtn, true);
                disableObject(formId, emailBtn, true);
            }
        }
    }

<t:div rendered="#{quote.containerTariffQuote}" style="width: 100%">
                        <t:div style="float: left; width: 50%">
                            <t:panelGrid columns="2" >
                                <t:selectBooleanCheckbox id="formContainerEstimateOrderForService"
                                    value="#{quote.forms.formContainerEstimateOrderForService}"
                                    onclick="manageCommandButtons(this)" />
                                <h:outputLabel for="formContainerEstimateOrderForService" 
                                    value="#{labels['l.pages.forms.forms.containerEstimateOrderForService']}&#160;#{labels['l.pages.forms.forms.requiresOrderNumber']}" />

                                <t:selectBooleanCheckbox id="formContainerOnePageEstimate"
                                    value="#{quote.forms.formContainerOnePageEstimate}"
                                    onclick="manageCommandButtons(this)" />
                                <h:outputLabel for="formContainerOnePageEstimate" value="#{labels['l.pages.forms.forms.onePageEstimate']}" />

                                <t:selectBooleanCheckbox id="formSurveyContainer"
                                    value="#{quote.forms.formSurvey}"
                                    onclick="manageCommandButtons(this)" />
                                <h:outputLabel for="formSurveyContainer" value="#{labels['l.pages.forms.forms.survey']}" />

                                <t:selectBooleanCheckbox id="formCityPointeReferralAuthContainer"
                                    value="#{quote.forms.formCityPointeReferralAuth}"
                                    onclick="manageCommandButtons(this)"/>
                                <h:outputLabel for="formCityPointeReferralAuthContainer"
                                    value="#{labels['l.pages.forms.forms.cityPointeReferralAuth']}"/>

                                <t:selectBooleanCheckbox id="formWorkOrderContainer"
                                    value="#{quote.forms.formWorkOrder}"
                                    onclick="manageCommandButtons(this)" />
                                <h:outputLabel for="formWorkOrderContainer" value="#{labels['l.pages.forms.forms.workOrder']}" />
                            </t:panelGrid>
                        </t:div>
                        <t:div style="float: right; width: 50%">
                            <t:panelGrid columns="2">
                                <t:selectBooleanCheckbox id="formContainerConfidentialWorksheet"
                                    value="#{quote.forms.formContainerConfidentialWorksheet}"
                                    onclick="manageCommandButtons(this)" />
                                <h:outputLabel for="formContainerConfidentialWorksheet"
                                    value="#{labels['l.pages.forms.forms.confidentialWorksheet']}" />                           
                            </t:panelGrid>
                         </t:div>
                    </t:div>
```

I would like all the checkboxes to be recognized in checkboxCollection.

I am using tomahawk 1.1.9, richfaces 3.3, and myfaces 1.2.

Comment: I think this is because it has a different parentTBODY as the others

Comment: You are correct. Thx for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Since you moved it to its own panelgrid, the selection of the checkboxes does not include the moved one since it now has a different parentTBODY. Correct your selection mechanism to also retrieve checkboxes below the other TBODY

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed it.

I added a styleClass attribute to both main divs which is being used as a selector.
IE:
  `<t:div id="containerQuoteSummaryForms" forceId="true" styleClass="checkBoxesSelector"....>`

I also changed the javascript method to use JQuery to get the checkboxes inside the div.

IE:
    `var checkBoxCollection =  jQuery(checkbox).closest('.checkBoxesSelector').find('input');`